# List by date is it <ol> or <ul>?

Tags: html, semantics

I have a list of newsletters like this:

1. Newsletter Jan
2. Newsletter Feb
3. Newsletter Mar
4. Newsletter May

I logically order them by date but the numeration does not really *mean* anything. So my question is what is semantically correct? to use `<ol>` or `ul`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are listed in order, then `<OL>`. Although I don't think it is a huge deal either way.

Answer (score 1):

From a UI perspective, there's no need to have a number and a date, it's just confusing.  If you're going to be super anal about definitions though, I guess an appropriately styled `ol` would be better.  But don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

From a strictly semantic sense, any list of items that has an ordering to it (dates included) should be marked up as an `<ol>`, since the `<ol>` tag indicates it's contents are an *ordered* list.

That being said, I agree with @Dave that the numeric list indicators are unlikely to be needed (depending on the rest your design, of course), and could be hidden with CSS. Depending on the browsers you are targeting, adjusting the margin and/or padding will hide them.

The reason it matters is because non-visual browsers, such as screen readers or text-based browsers like Lynx can offer their users additional functionality for an ordered list than an unordered one. For example, it makes *much* more sense for a user to jump to the 8th item in an ordered list, since they are more likely to know what that item is based on ordering, than it does to jump to the 8th item in an unordered list. (ie. they can do a binary search on an ordered list, but not an unordered one)